# Call method in another method?

Tags: android, class, methods

Hi I tried to call a method inside my mainactivity from a ScreenReceiver class. I found this and implemented it into my code.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // ScreenRecv
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new ScreenReceiver();
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
    }

    // Toast(String)
    public void Toast(String text) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

ScreenReceiver:

```
package com.wifitimer;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static boolean wasScreenOn = true;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            new MainActivity().Toast("Screen Off");
            wasScreenOn = false;
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            new MainActivity().Toast("Screen On");
            wasScreenOn = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I get no errors but the Toast also doesn't show. Any ideas?

LogCat:

```
04-16 00:53:35.470: I/WifiManager(19123): setWifiEnabled : true
04-16 00:53:57.135: D/AndroidRuntime(19123): Shutting down VM
04-16 00:53:57.135: W/dalvikvm(19123): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416922a0)
04-16 00:53:57.140: E/AndroidRuntime(19123): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-16 00:53:57.140: E/AndroidRuntime(19123): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF flg=0x50000010 } in com.wifitimer.ScreenReceiver@42312238
04-16 00:53:57.140: E/AndroidRuntime(19123):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:765)
04-16 00:53:57.140: E/AndroidRuntime(19123):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
04-16 00:53:57.140: E/AndroidRuntime(19123):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-16 00:53:57.140: E/AndroidRuntime(19123):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-16 00:53:57.140: E/AndroidRuntime(19123):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
04-16 00:53:57.140: E/AndroidRuntime(19123):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-16 00:53:57.140: E/AndroidRuntime(19123):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-16 00:53:57.140: E/AndroidRuntime(19123):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
04-16 00:53:57.140: E/AndroidRuntime(19123):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
04-16 00:53:57.140: E/AndroidRuntime(19123):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-16 00:53:57.140: E/AndroidRuntime(19123): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-16 00:53:57.140: E/AndroidRuntime(19123):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:101)
04-16 00:53:57.140: E/AndroidRuntime(19123):    at com.wifitimer.MainActivity.Toast(MainActivity.java:107)
04-16 00:53:57.140: E/AndroidRuntime(19123):    at com.wifitimer.ScreenReceiver.onReceive(ScreenReceiver.java:13)
04-16 00:53:57.140: E/AndroidRuntime(19123):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:755)
04-16 00:53:57.140: E/AndroidRuntime(19123):    ... 9 more
04-16 00:53:57.445: I/Process(19123): Sending signal. PID: 19123 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Refactor your code to show what components you are really using. Your question is confusing without such information.

Comment: I have added the full code above :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your call shouldn't actually work, since you need to feed `Context` as a first parameter to `makeText`. And since your class doesn't derive from Context or an Activity or anything like that, it shouldn't even compile.

Look at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#makeText%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20int%29).

With your code showing now, the problem you currently have is this:

```
   new MainActivity().Toast("Screen Off");
```

You already have an instanced MainActivity, you don't need to instance a new one. Now, if you want to use the method of the first class, one thing you could do is add a constructor for your ScreenReceiver

```
MainActivity myContext;
public ScreenReceiver(MainActivity context){
    myContext = context;
}
```

and in the onReceive method change that line to

```
myContext.Toast("Screen Off");
```

and to instance your changed class, you'd need to change that line to

```
BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new ScreenReceiver(this);
```

Comment: B is a subclass of mainactivity

Comment: Even so. You'd need to change the "this" to MainActivity.this for your code to work. (Depends on the name of your classes, of course)

Comment: Hey thanks man. I just tried your suggestions but still doesn't work. I added the LogCat to the main post above.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a Toast, the first parameter needs to be a Context. Thus, either B needs to be a subclass of activity/service/application, or you need to pass a reference to B in it's constructor to a valid Context. Alternatively you could subclass Application and provide a static getContext method.

Comment: B is a subclass of mainactivity

Comment: Please don't suggest creating static getContext methods. This is a good start for spaghetti code.

Comment: I have added the full code above. I added the MainActivity.this to the toast and still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You cannot instantiate Activities directly. Use `startActivity(this, B.class);` inside A and call methodB from inside B lifecycle method.</strike>

**Edit to match edited question:**

If you just want to show Toast, do it in `BroadcastReceiver` directly:

```
Toast.makeText(context, "Screen On/Off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

If you want to call a function on component (`Activity`), which created your `BroadcastReceiver`, it's best to add callback interface and implement that in `Activity`, send via constructor (like DigCamara said in his answer) or setter to `BroadcastReceiver` and call when needed.

Notes:

1. You don't instantiate `Activities` and `Services` directly. It simply wont work.
2. You need to unregister `BroadcastReceiver` in a matching function (in your case `onDestroy`).
3. Don't keep data in static variables: `public static boolean wasScreenOn = true;`. You will lose this data after process is killed and restarted.